# Can I avoid Firestore transaction when using firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp( ) with other FieldValue functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have two questions here.

1. If I use `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp( )` to update a single field, is transaction needed or this function will take care of the atomic update on the server?
2. If I user multiple FieldValue functions together to update a single object like the following example, can I do it without transaction, and atomic update will happen for all fields?

> ```
> this.afs.doc('path').update({
>   date: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp( ),
>   array: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion('value'),
>   count: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
> });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

> If I use firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp( ) to update a single field, is transaction needed or this function will take care of the atomic update on the server?

It is "atomic" just like any other document write, in that the write happens just once with the timestamp computed on the server at the time it was received.

> If I user multiple FieldValue functions together to update a single object like the following example, can I do it without transaction, and atomic update will happen for all fields?

It is also still "atomic" in that there is just one document write with values computed on the server.  They all get written at the same time.  The FieldValue tokens all essentially act inside if a transaction that the client is not involved with.